# Can't assign value into function's optional property with didSet

Tags: swift

Here's my testing code written in Xcode playground :

```
import UIKit

func test() -> Int {
    var value: Int? {
        didSet {
//            print("\(value)") // while un-comment this line, value could be returned as `1` normally
            print("i am triggered")
        }
    }

    let arr: [Int] = Array(0...1)
    arr.forEach { _ in
        if value != nil {
            value! += 1
        } else {
            value = 0
        }
    }

    return value ?? 999
}

print(test())
```

Code now is printing `999`, because `value` is always `nil` even assigned value in forEach exec.

However, if I try to un-comment the print command in observer, or put `value` out of method to be global value : Output will be `1` normally.

In my understanding, `var value: Int?` default as nil already, and after 1st operation in forEach, it should be 0 set by the else case. Therefore, result should be `0 + 1 = 1` after the 2nd run.

Is there something I am missing? Appreciated if someone could explain a bit, many thank!

Comment: Is this just an exercise in learning what this code is doing? Or are you trying to use this for something? Could you explain what it is you're trying to do with this code as there might be a better way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister This code seems to be demonstrating a strange bug being caused by applying `didSet` to a local variable instead of a property.

Comment: Also... wait... what? This feels broken. I just put it into a Playground and I now see your issue. 

Comment: @HangarRash yeah, I just appreciated that. Just a little late 

Comment: I love this. It never would have occurred to me to try using property observers with a local variable. I think I smell a compiler bug.

Comment: This might be a Playground bug or some kind of overly-aggressive optimisation which affects behaviour. If you move the declaration of `value` outside of the `test` method then it works as you expect.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth it's not confined to Playgrounds. Just spun up a SwiftUI app that runs this in the `.onAppear` and the same bug appears.

Comment: The `forEach` (or maybe the closure) seems to be a contributing factor. If you remove that and just execute the if-else in a simple `for i in 0...1` then it works. Very strange! I

Comment: @GeoffHackworth I just came to report the same finding. :) The closure definitely seems to be a contributing factor. In fact, I just replicated the issue using a non-optional version of `value`.

Comment: Yeah, just testing with a non-optional too. Plus, you can even print the `oldValue` and `newValue` in the didSet and willSet and the bug still occurs.

Comment: I just put the if-else in a closure in a local variable and called it twice. It works. Even if I call it in a `(0…1).forEach`.

Comment: [There's a 5-year-old bug logged about this, with quite a following thread!](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/49805)

Comment: @Jessy Is that really the same issue? The issue in this question seems quite different. This issue appears even if optionals are not involved. This issue only appears when the local variable is modified inside a closure, only if the local variable has a property observer, and the observer (either willSet or didSet) makes no reference to the observed variable. And under those conditions, the variable's value is lost outside of the closure. The issue you linked is about property observers being called when they shouldn't.